# Does chrome process sites with www prefix differently?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, ssl

I host a number of sites from our partners.  These sites are all subdomains of our partners top level domains.  In response to the new push to https I have obtained certificates and created the appropriate bindings.  All is good when the url:

subdomain.partner.edu

is used.  The request redirects to https and all is good.  My issue at this point is when the url:

www.subdomain.partner.edu is used.

In ie and Firefox the www remains and I get a certificate error (the cert is for subdomain.partner.edu not www.subdomain.partner.edu).  This I understand. 
 However, in chrome the www. is removed and the site loads correctly.  Why is chrome different?  There is no url rewrite on the site to remove www.  Sites are hosted on iis 8.

As always any clarification is greatly appreciated

Comment: Just as a small comment, but in Chrome 65, the `www` for e.g. `www.subdomain.mydomain.com` isn't removed for me.

Comment: Testing a number of browsers/versions/os's on my stand alone mac the www prefix is not removed.  It is an issue locally with some chrome browsers.  it is possible it is a url / search feature that may be due to the dual nature of the url field in chrome